# Cannot solely remove M value of Shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, ogr2ogr, z-value, m-values

I have a couple of Shapefiles which are of geometry type ZM (like `PolygonZM`, `MultiLineStringZM`, etc.), however my database (a PostGIS database) is of geometry type Z (like `PolygonZ`, `MultiPointZ`, etc.). When I import my shapefile into database, it will of course report an error. However, when I convert these Shapefiles, I find that M values cannot be removed without removing Z value.
Here are my efforts:
1. In ArcMap, use Feature Class to Feature Class in ArcToolbox, click "Environment" and disable M value there. However, output Shapefiles still have M values.
2. Using Export in QGIS, and choose `PolygonZ` or other geometry types with Z only in `SHPT` field. Again, output Shapefiles still have M values.
3. Use `ogr2ogr`. Here is the command line:

```
ogr2ogr -nlt polygonz new.shp old.shp
```

Again, output Shapefiles still have M values.
However, if I discard Z values as well:

```
ogr2ogr -nlt polygon new.shp old.shp
```

Output Shapefiles will have neither Z nor M values.
But when I try to add Z again, like:

```
ogr2ogr -nlt polygonz new1.shp new.shp
```

Both Z and M will be added, thus returning to `PolygonZM`.
Since these shapefiles have no actual Z values at all, I can safely discard Z values along with M values if I only need to deal with these files themselves. However, in my database, geometry columns are storing Z values, and they cannot be discarded. Can anyone tell me why can't I just discard M values and preserve Z values for these Shapefiles?

Comment: Copy features tool with M disabled?

Comment: Yes, it works fine, just tested it again to be sure.

Comment: perhaps a workaround would be to add the z values to the attribute table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shapefiles with Z contain also always M. See the technical specification of PointZ from https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf. Same applies to other geometry types with Z.

> A PointZ consists of a triplet of double-precision coordinates in the
>   order X, Y, Z plus a measure.
>
> ```
> PointZ
> {
> Double X  //X coordinate
> Double Y  //Y coordinate
> Double Z  //Z coordinate
> Double M  //M measure
> }
> ```

You can drop M when you convert data into PostGIS with ogr2ogr just as you tried to drop it from the shapefile with `-nlt polygonz`.

Comment: Maybe it's a shame for me, who worked in GIS for about five years, have not ever read the definition of shapefile...